# Fiware Scorpio appending new attribute to existing entity

Tags: fiware, fiware-scorpio

I tried to append a new entity to an existing entity.
Same as in the official example on:
https://scorpio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API_walkthrough.html#updating-an-entity-appending-to-an-entity

Try to append attribute **humidity**:

```
curl localhost:9090/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/house2%3Asmartrooms%3Aroom1/attrs -s -S -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Link: https://pastebin.com/raw/Mgxv2ykn' -d @- <<EOF
{
        "humidity": {
        "value": 34,
        "unitCode": "PER",
        "type": "Property",
        "providedBy": {
                "type": "Relationship",
                "object": "smartbuilding:house2:sensor2222"
        }
  }
}
```

But I receive the error:

```
{
  https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/default-context/notUpdated : [ {
    https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/attributeName : {
      "@id" : https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/default-context/humidity
    },
    https://uri.etsi.org/ngsi-ld/reason : "attribute not found in original entity"
  } ]
}
```

Can anybody tell me, if they encounter the same problem?
Or how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you want to append new attribute in existing entity so you should use POST request instead of PATCH.

Sorry for inconvenience, we will update in document as well.

Thanks,
Amit Raghav.